# Posting a Model from JQuery to ASP.NET Core WebAPI Failure

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a project and I am getting stumped on something that should be relatively trivial. My project is an ASP.NET Core Web Pages project, but it also has a single API Controller in there for certain features that just need an API. My Controller looks like the following:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class OrderController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("AddItem")]
        public IActionResult AddItem(AddToCartModel model)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

To post data to it, I have the follow jQuery code in one of my pages.

```
                var addToCart = {
                    Quantity: qtty,
                    ProductId: pid,
                    Success: true,
                    Message: ""
                };

                console.log(addToCart);
                var response = $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/api/Order/AddItem',
                    data: JSON.stringify( addToCart ),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json'
                });
```

And just in case it matters to anyone, this is the C# model.

```
public class AddToCartModel
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public bool Success { get; set; }

        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to post the data I get back a server error (415). Oddly enough, if I remove the model from the   Controller method's parameters, or declare it as dynamic, I will get through to my NotImplemented error. And if I declare the parameter as dynamic, then I can explore and see my properties on the object. Obviously though, I dont want to simply make everything dynamic in my code. I feel like, maybe, this could have something to do with JSON encoding, but ...shrug??

Anyway, maybe my brain is just fried for the night, so I thought I would post it here in the hopes that there is probably going to be an obvious answer I am completely overlooking.

Comment: don't use `JSON.stringify` when posting the data, just use `data: addToCart`.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried that and it didn't work out for me.

Comment: Strange, normally the `dataType` and `contentType` are not required either as jQuery does the parsing automatically. I never had problems with it but that does not really help you, sorry.

Comment: Yeah no worries. I think it has something to do with how ASP.NET Core's new JSON parser is handling this. The above code I entered would have worked great in ASP.NET 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well I have an answer now, I tired it in Postman, got back a detailed answer. It was bizarre. Basically it said that it couldn't convert the value of ProductId into an int. This is of course bizarre because its an int already, and even represented as a string C# should have no problem converting a value of "1" (in this case that was the value I was passing) into an Int with a value of 1.

Sure enough though, I changed my code slightly to parseInt(pid) and it started to work.